# php sending http headers

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I use php function `file_get_contents` and one of params is http headers. I make them such like this:

```
if (strpos($key, 'HTTP_') === 0) {
    $key = strtolower(strtr(substr($key, 5), '_', '-'));
    $this->headers .= $key . ': ' . $value . '\r\n';
}
```

but here is a problem, I should send headers in double quotes like this:

```
"Connection: close\r\nContent-Length: $data_len\r\n"
```

Here is an example of how do I make request:

```
$opts = array(
        'http'  =>  array(
            'method'    => "GET",
            'header'    => $this->headers
        )
);

$this->data = file_get_contents('http://phd.yandex.net/detect', false, stream_context_create($opts));
```

but it is fails. If I replace `$this->headers` in array with a custom string of http headers, everything works fine.

how to make it works right?

Comment: Have you considered [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)?

Comment: What's your custom string look like, v.s. what the above code generates?

Comment: Is it a typo that you omitted the quotes around `\r\n`?

Comment: You are missing quotes around the `\r\n` in the first code section - could this be the problem? I suspect it will not parse but you never know...

Comment: missing quotes around the `\r\n` it is a typo

Comment: The `'\r\n'` be in double quotes.  `"\r\n"`.   Example: http://ideone.com/cHl8p

Comment: You need double quotes around the \r\n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\r\n` needs to be in *double quotes* so that the characters are parsed correctly. Everything else can be appended using single quotes, no problem. Only a few things are parsed using the backslash in single quoted strings, such as `\\`, `\'`, and `\"`.

Your headers are looking like this:

```
Key: Value\r\nKey: value\r\n
```

Where the `\r\n` is appearing as an actual string, when you want it to look like this:

```
Key: Value
Key: Value
```

Where the `\r\n` actually creates a new line in the headers.